# Should ergonomics be added to password strength meters?

Tags: login, password, ergonomics, error-prevention

After getting locked out of my account for typing in my password incorrectly several times in a row, I realized that the password I chose is too prone to typos and has resulted in locked accounts.

It occurred to me that ergonomics *could* be part of a password strength meter. Either through ergonomic analysis or through having the user confirm the password in three or four fields on user sign-up forms.

Are there best practices for mitigating lock-outs due to user password typos?

Comment: Step 1: Require increasingly complex passwords.
Step 2: Force user to enter complex password more times than is necessary.
Step 3: Yell at user for choosing a complex password.
Step 4: Profit!

Comment: Serious comment: Any determination of ergonomics would have to take the user's language and keyboard layout into account.

Comment: That would be a daunting undertaking. I suppose I'll use your first comment to create a wonderful ergonomic password generator app. Ca-Ching!

Comment: This type of ergonomic "helper" won't strengthen the password, it would actually weaken it.

Comment: users don't like entering the same data twice. Any one slightly skilled with a computer just cuts-and-pastes into each field anyways, therefor bypassing the purpose of asking multiple times. You could block pasting, but now you're just annoying those skilled users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh dear. Don't ever, and I mean ever, create barriers for users when signing up. Having the user confirm the password several times (even more than once), is a barrier which will affect sign up rates.

There are actually a lot of ways you can fix the signup and login process such as:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9fEHB.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

You could have a checkbox (or icon) to reveal the password where the user can confirm what he/she wrote was correct. This solution also works really well in the signup process because it's less form fields.

***The less form fields in a sign up process the better.*** This is because signing up for an account is a painful process. Adding countless fields and pages to make the process longer is just irritating and will drastically reduce the conversion rates.

Comment: That's a clever solution as well. Too bad I've only ever seen this on Mobile sign-ups.

Comment: I'm a huge fan of this because again, in this case, less is more :)

Answer (score 2):

The only example I see commonly is an indication that caps lock is on.

[image: Example]

As the combination of letters, numbers, and various symbols can vary greatly, this seems to be one of the only common errors I know of aside from producing password hints and an easy Password reset process.

> having the user confirm the password in three or four fields on user sign-up forms

Might this type of repetition would irritate users? Personally, I would just type my password onto Notepad, then Paste it in for all the boxes if I saw that - but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

How many times would mean several though? If it means 4 or 5 times, that shouldn't make you lock out your users, unless for example you are an online banking portal with a very low password complexity requirement. The justification for locking out accounts is to prevent brute force techniques, not slippery fingers. I feel ergonomics will limit complexity and make it easier to guess passwords...